# For an interval $[a, b]$ we obtain $\lambda [a, b] \subseteq [x, y]$ for every $[x, y]$

Tags: analysis

Find a closed interval such as $[a, b]$, such that for every closed interval $[x, y]$ on the real numbers we have  $\lambda [a,b] \subseteq [x,y]$. My condition is: this interval is either totally negative or totally positive (that is, the zero point should not be in this interval).
If not, how is it proven that there are no non-trivial (i.e. containing at least $2$ points) intervals $[a, b]$ that meet these conditions

*Hint.* For example let $[a, b]=[-1, 1] ,  [x, y]=[2, 8]$ then there is no $\lambda$ such that  $\lambda [-1, 1] \subseteq [2, 8]$. Hence $[-1, 1]$
Cannot be the desired interval. Also we want to get an interval that has the above condition. Pay attention that $\lambda [a, b] = [\lambda a, \lambda b]$ for $\lambda \geq 0$ but $\lambda [a,b] = [\lambda b, \lambda a]$ for $\lambda \leq 0$.

*Remark.*
I simulated this matter. For example, in real numbers, the number one is a generator of the entire real space. I want to find an interval that is the generator of the entire intervals on the real numbers. In our real relationship, it is equality, but here it is a normal relationship (i.e. subset). be I have defined that I will check whether it will be successful or not. Therefore, if I don't succeed with one interval, maybe I will succeed with two intervals and reach my goal (compare with the  dimention definition in the real space). My interval should not contain zero. Because of dimension definition.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ given to you or it can  depend on $[x,y]$?

Comment: Where did you find this question? As I understand them, there are no non-trivial (i.e. containing at least $2$ points) intervals $[a, b]$ that meet these conditions.

Comment: $\lambda$ is an arbitrary real number, it should only be chosen that the above relation holds

Comment: I simulated this matter. For example, in real numbers, the number one is a generator of the entire real space. I want to find an interval that is the generator of the entire intervals on the real numbers. In our real relationship, it is equality, but here it is a normal relationship. be I have defined that I will check whether it will be successful or not. Therefore, if it is open, surely the sum of two intervals will reach my goal. My interval should not contain zero.

Comment: Could you add some space in your text? It's really awful to read..